# On the products view page, some content of details are displaying on the top bar below body

Tags: magento-2.0.4

After installing **magento 2.0.4**, I have migrated my data from old to new version. But when I view product a small amount of text is appearing at the top of the page. This is not on every product page on few it is showing like that. I checked on the product page from back end everything is proper. I am not getting why is it like that can anyone help me in this.
thank you.

Comment: It will be good to understand the problem very well if you add a screenshot of the problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just go to your database and find  `ui_bookmark` table.
Go to row with **namespace product_listing and identifier as current**

Edit above row and set value inside **`config`** field

```
find "paging":{"options":{"20":{"value":20,"label":20},"30":{"value":30,"label":30},"50":{"value":50,"label":50},"100":{"value":100,"label":100},"200":{"value":200,"label":200}},"value":1500},
```

Set 100 instead of 1500 inside value and check again.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check in adminpanel for that product.

Go to `Admin -> Products` 
Open Prodcut CLick on left sidebar,

Go to

> Search Engine Optimization tab

Check `Meta Keywords`, `Meta Description`, `Description` field if it contens html tag then remove it. Or clear the value of meta keywords and check.

After that reindex your site.

Comment: No there is not html tags in meta keywords and meta description

Comment: can you show your page snapshot for more info

Comment: just remove your description and remove all meta filed from search engine optimization and check again.

Comment: Removing product description also removes the top content. but we need description.

Comment: using above have you seen proper page?

Comment: yes i opened the same product page

Comment: after remove description and meta fields your page have remove error from top, Right?

Comment: yes, but i need description for product. :(

Comment: you can check in your description, any tag mismatch or not properly closed. This causes error in your page.

Comment: I checked tags are all correct

Comment: In inspect element li tag is containing whole page including meta tags: see below inspect code:<body data-container="body" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" itemscope="itemscope" class="catalog-product-view product-gc-initial-pressable-301 categorypath-laboratory-metal-free-restoration-html category-metal-free-restoration page-layout-1column" cz-shortcut-listen="true" aria-busy="false"><li>All components are perfectly matched to each other</li>
<li>Cross-system logic for all ma"/&gt;
<meta name="keywords" content="GC Initial Pressable">
....all description all code then li ends</li>

Comment: Try like this , You can set description using wysiwyg editor first cut desctription , click on wysiwyg button below desctiption and paste in editor and submit.

Comment: tried, it didn't work. also i remove tags and put only words still it is showing at the top

Comment: use reindexing command.

Comment: Hey i got a solution of creating that products again. thank you so much for the help :)

Comment: Hi just one more thing, i just went in backend and i wanted to search a product so i increase the per page product and made it custom to 1500 :( and now it is giving error as something went wrong and not showing me products list in dashbord. it is just loading

Comment: you have set less product because 1500 product takes much time to load collection.

Comment: Now how to change it? :( it is not allowing me as it is just loading and loading and giving message attention something went wrong.

Comment: you can logout and go again product page

Comment: i did that it is just loading and not showing product list :(

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Sorry to i posted on answer as i was not getting option to attach. In screenshot if you see there is a content coming on the top above header. the content is two starting lines of product description.